# Azure Maps Cannot read properties of undefined reading '_clickTolerance'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-maps

When editing a geometry shape I sometimes get the js error showing in the debug:

[image]

[image]

The issue occurs when I try to drag the geometry and manipulate the shape, such as a rectangle or polygon. The error message is intermittent. I've tried searching MS docs and cant find any reference to the '_clickTolerence' parameter so I'm not sure if there is an parameter that we can set for this? totally lost on this one...

Using the following script from MS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure which version this relates to but as of Oct 2021 is the current version...

The pattern of behaviour seems to be that the error only shows when I select one of the round dots to change the shape, but on the occasion where the whole geometry tries to move is when the error message appears. It seems that the drag and edit control doesn't always recognise when I'm trying to manipulate the shape rather than dragging and moving the whole object which is when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried searching MS docs and cant find any reference to the '_clickTolerence' parameter

[Marker._clickTolerance](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/blob/main/src/ui/marker.ts#L67) is an internal property of maplibre's (that MapControl utilizes underneath) **Marker** implementation.

The reason why you are seeing this exception is because move handler is being called on the marker that is removed at same time (drag handles are removed on move).

Thanks for reporting this, the issue has been fixed on the drawing module side, I will update this answer once the new drawing module release is out.

Comment: Please can you provide an update on when this is going to be fixed.  I'm also getting an error "Uncaught Error: Error: Singular matrix. Points are likely coplanar." when trying to resize an image layer which may be related to this as I'm using the drawing manager with a shape to represent the outer boundary of the image layer being resized using the drag handles.